# Validating two checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have this custom validation code for checking that two checkboxes are checked but displaying only one message for both of them.

```
public class SeveralCheckboxesRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string[] _properties;

    public SeveralCheckboxesRequiredAttribute(params string[] properties)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "You must confirm you have entered the correct information ";
        ErrorMessage += "for your income and expenditure. Wrong information may result in ";
        ErrorMessage += "us not being able to lend to you at this time or in the future.";

        _properties = properties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_properties == null || _properties.Length < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var prop in _properties)
        {
            var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(prop);
            var propertyValue = (bool)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (!propertyValue)
            {
                // At least one property is false  => the model is not valid
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "severalcheckboxesrequired"
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters["properties"] = string.Join(",", _properties);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

And the client side is:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('severalcheckboxesrequired', function (value, element, params) {
    var props = params.properties.split(','),
        isValid = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var property = props[i];
        if (!$('#' + property).is(':checked')) {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}, '');

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'severalcheckboxesrequired',
    ['properties'],
    function (options) {
        options.rules['severalcheckboxesrequired'] = options.params;
        options.messages['severalcheckboxesrequired'] = options.message;
    }
);
```

The model properties related with this would be:

```
[SeveralCheckboxesRequired("AccurateInformation", "FutureInformation")]
[Display(Name = "Please tick here to confirm you have provided accurate information.")]
public bool AccurateInformation { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Please tick here to confirm that you have considered potential future information.")]
public bool FutureInformation { get; set; }
```

And the view contains this

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <div class="checkboxWrapper">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccurateInformation)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccurateInformation)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FutureInformation)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FutureInformation)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_12">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccurateInformation)
</div>
```

My aim would be to highlight them whenever they are not checked which currently is not working. But that's a minor concern for now. The main problem is that for achieving this I just decorate one of them as if I use an attribute at a class level I'm not able to have the client side validation.

And that causes and issue in this kind of scenario: You submit the form with only the first one (the decorated one) checked and not the second one and you get the client side error (not highlighted though but you get the message). Then you check the second one and the validator method is obviously not trigger and you have to actually hit the submit button to make the message disappear. Is there a way of binding the second one to the same validator method? is there a better solution for this? would even be possible to highlight the fawled checkbox?

Thanks

UPDATE: In a second stint on this issue I came up with a far from ideal workaround, but in case someone run into the same problem and don't have anything better...

I add the class 'shared' to the two checkboxes (notice I have to use Html.CheckBoxFor and not EditorFor in order to add the class)

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <div class="checkboxWrapper">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccurateInformation)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccurateInformation, new {@class='shared'})
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FutureInformation, new {@class='shared'})
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FutureInformation)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_12">
```

And this code in the js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.shared').on('change', function () {
        $('.shared[data-val-severalcheckboxesrequired]').valid();
    });
});
```

Which basically triggers the validation on the annotated checkbox every time any of the dependants (or itself) changes, as the custom validator check that all of them are checked every time this trigger happened all of them have to checked in order to make the message disappear.

Comment: Why doesn't the JS validator method fire in the second scenario? That is, even if the first checkbox is valid, that validation should still be happening, and you should focus your troubleshooting there.

Comment: @JeradRose, it's fired when you submit the form and it works. But not "on the fly" for the checkbox which is not decorated

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, the only way for that to happen is for the rule to be wired to both checkboxes -- `GetClientValidationRules` has to run on both elements, and the `data-` attributes are needed on both elements. What happens if you include the rule on both properties? I know this isn't the ultimate solution, but just seeing if that gets you closer to your desired results.

Comment: @JeradRose, Problem then is that I get two error messages and I need to display just one. Otherwise actually I could avoid the custom validation